# Can i auth with api with auth structure of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I want make an API for used on both front-end and admin panel with using Laravel auth structure (with make:auth) and API Authentication (with Passport) for manage all operation of actions.

My "routes/api.php" file;

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'api.admin.'], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        //
    });

});
```

My Auth\LoginController file;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->logout();
        session()->flash('message', 'Some goodbye message');
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

When i call "/api/admin/login" url with post method and "email", "password" data, it returns following error;

```
RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.
```

I think solved above error with following method in $middlewareGroup in Kernel.php api group;
My app/Http/Kernel.php file;

> ```
> \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
> \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
> ```

**Session store not set on request.** error is solved but, it returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException now.

I can solved these problems with other method but i want use auth standart of Laravel.

Is this possible?

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you mean to have a `post` request to logout? If you just use `Route::get` for logout, then visiting the logout URL will log you out.

Comment: My problem is on login action. I don't tested logout action :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible although it's a bit more involved than just switching the login url. You're going for the [Password Grant Flow](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#password-grant-tokens) so user's can authenticate with their existing email and password credentials.

You do not need to enable the session for this to work. The basic run down is you post your email and password to a route which proxies the request to the OAuth2 server. You'll relay the authentication and refresh tokens back to the user, who's responsibility it is then to attach the access token to each subsequent request using the `Authorization: Bearer LongEncryptedTokenHere...` header.

To make things easier, Laravel offers the `CreateFreshApiTokens` middleware which will automatically authorize and refresh the token each request. You can read about [Consuming Your API With JavaScript here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

An example of requesting a token using the `password` grant and Guzzle:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

From [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#password-grant-tokens)

Comment: Thank you, You are awesome. I never thought of that. Your answer very very very helpful for me... Now i have to solving register user,  logout operation with api.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a session separately as middleware to the $middlewareGroups.

It should contain **\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],

        'sessions' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ]
    ];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () {
    Route::resource(...);
});
```

Comment: That's does not worked. MethodNotAllowedHttpException error is still returns. Thank you.

Comment: @FGDeveloper Simply no one uses an session for api, but a token is used, try https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth